# mono crashes with System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer doesn't implement interface System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize

Tags: linux, .net-4.0, mono

I'm getting the following error from mono:
System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer doesn't implement interface System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize

The software is Chummergen, my system is fedora 17 (Chummergen.com)
My google results turned up, that this is a known problem, that there is a fix but it won't be ported back to mono 2.8... (which has been a really old post by itself now)

which brings me to the following questions...
a) Is there anything I can do to make it run?
b) can I get a newer version of mono for my fedora?
c) can I use the SUSE RPM or should I grab the source (and which rpm file should I use?)
d) is there a readme/guid/faq on building mono from source?

Thanks in advance
Fred

Comment: I reccomend that you upgrade you mono / MonoDevelopment environment. CHEERS

Comment: Seems to be fixed in Mono 3.2 on Ubuntu. A guide for compiling from source on Fedora: http://forums.osgrid.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=4625

Comment: I have the smae issue. Moving to 3.2 does not fix it.